# How to plot squares using lists in python?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a graph of squares using two lists of data; I've found code that will do this if the position for each square is manually put in, however my lists are much too long for this to work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

colors = [ 'crimson', 'dodgerblue', 'limegreen', 'black']

side = 2
square1 = [1, 1.3]
square2 = [2.1, 0.5]
square3 = [1.3, 1.6]
square4 = [1.7, 2.8]
squares = [square1, square2, square3, square4]

for square, col in zip(squares, colors):
    x = square[0]
    y = square[1]
    plt.plot([x, x + side, x + side, x, x],
             [y, y, y + side, y + side, y],
             color=col, linestyle='solid')
plt.title('square pattern')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

I've tried to modify the code to make an i amount of squares using a for loop but it doesn't work, it seems like "square" doesn't want to be indexed. Is there any way around this?

```
Left = [264, 268, 268, 268, 272, 272, 272, 276, 276, 304, 308, 308, 308, 392, 444, 468, 472, 472, 476, 476, 984, 988, 996, 1000, 1008, 1012, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1024, 1028, 1032, 1040, 1056, 1100, 1132, 1184, 1184, 1228, 1228, 1232, 1232, 1276, 1332]
Right = [284, 292, 296, 304, 308, 312, 316, 316, 316, 316, 316, 320, 320, 408, 468, 480, 484, 488, 488, 492, 992, 996, 1012, 1012, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1028, 1028, 1028, 1036, 1040, 1040, 1044, 1044, 1044, 1044, 1056, 1084, 1160, 1196, 1200, 1236, 1236, 1236, 1236, 1268, 1292, 1340]

for i in range (0,len(Left)):
    side = Right[i] - Left[i] #side length should be difference of list "Right" and "Left"
    square = [Left[i],1] # I don't really care about y, I just need it to be a constant length
    squares = square
    break

for square, col in zip(squares, colors):
    x = square
    y = square
    plt.plot([x, x + side, x + side, x, x],
             [y, y, y + side, y + side, y],
             color=col, linestyle='solid')
    
    
plt.title('square pattern')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The line of `break` in the loop `for i in range (0,len(Left)):` would break the loop after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're expecting the output to look like..

With your current code, you are breaking out of the first for loop after you've only added a single value to the squares list, so when you run your second list, it's not creating all of the squares you were expecting. I removed the break, and created another list to keep track of the side lengths. Once you have side lengths + left coordinate, you can zip over those two since they are the same length, creating a rectangle for each.

```py
Left = [264, 268, 268, 268, 272, 272, 272, 276, 276, 304, 308, 308, 308, 392, 444, 468, 472, 472, 476, 476, 984, 988, 996, 1000, 1008, 1012, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1024, 1028, 1032, 1040, 1056, 1100, 1132, 1184, 1184, 1228, 1228, 1232, 1232, 1276, 1332]
Right = [284, 292, 296, 304, 308, 312, 316, 316, 316, 316, 316, 320, 320, 408, 468, 480, 484, 488, 488, 492, 992, 996, 1012, 1012, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1028, 1028, 1028, 1036, 1040, 1040, 1044, 1044, 1044, 1044, 1056, 1084, 1160, 1196, 1200, 1236, 1236, 1236, 1236, 1268, 1292, 1340]

squares = [] # Keeps track left coordinate
sides = [] # Keeps track of the side lengths, which you said is the difference of right and left
for i in range (0,len(Left)):
    side = Right[i] - Left[i] #side length should be difference of list "Right" and "Left"
    squares.append(Left[i]) # I don't really care about y, I just need it to be a constant length
    sides.append(side)

plt.axes() # reset plot
for x, side in zip(squares, sides):
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x,x), side, side)
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)

plt.title('square pattern')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

[image: matplot plot of squares]

Comment: Thank you so much! I slightly modified the code to rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x,1), side, side*10) and made the squares hollow and I got the results I needed, thanks for the help :)